How to enable PHP on OS X Sonoma?
I have a new Mac Studio running OS X 14.5 Sonoma.  I am trying to configure my Apache2 server to run PHP.
Following suggestions found in various web pages I've done the following...
I've modified /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and created /etc/apache2/users/<myshortusername>.conf to enable Apache2.  This seems to have worked.  Both http://localhost/index.html and http://localhost/~<myshortusername>/index.html display the expected output.
/etc/apache2/users/<myshortusername>.conf contains
<Directory "/Users/john/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .php
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require host localhost
</Directory>

[I'm suspicious of the AddHandler line.  That seems to be saying that .php files are handled by cgi-script?]
I installed PHP v8.2 using MacPorts.  I believe the command I used was
sudo port install php82

but I don't have a written record of this.
I then edited /etc/apache2/httpd.conf in an attempt to enable PHP.
I added
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php_module libexec/apache2/mod_php82.so

I changed
<IfModule dir_module>
    # DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

and
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

and
# LogLevel warn
LogLevel debug

and changed the definintion of ServerAdmin to a custom email address.
My test file (info.php) in ~<myshortusername>/Sites is
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Localhost</h1>
    <?php
        echo (phpinfo());   
    ?>
</body>
<html>

I then stopped and restarted the Apache server with
sudo launchctl remove org.apache2.httpd
sudo launchctl start -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

On typing http://localhost/~<myshortusername>/info.php into the address bar of my browser I see:

/private/var/log/apache2/error_log is empty.
Since I see you@example.com rather than my custom ServerAdmin and since error_log is empty, I think that my changes to httpd.conf aren't being picked up.
apachectl configtest returns Syntax OK.
What am I doing wrong?
Update
In response to @arkascha's comments below:
1.  Do you mean that
sudo launchctl remove org.apache2.httpd
sudo launchctl start -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

is not the appropriate way to stop and restart the server?  Is apachectl an alternative?
2.  I believe the log file entry is correct.  It is defined in the httpd.conf I am editing.
ls /private/var/log/apache2 gives access_log error_log.  access_log contains, for example,
localhost - - [07/Jul/2024:14:44:03 +0100] "GET /~<myshortusername>/index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
localhost - - [07/Jul/2024:14:44:09 +0100] "GET /~<myshortusername>/info.php HTTP/1.1" 500 528

which were the last two times I tested both index.html and info.php.  It remains empty.  In response to the comment immediately above the ErrorLog directive, there are no ~s define in (this) httpd.conf`.
3. Thank you for the reassurance regarding cgi-script.  I do have an AddHandler directive for .php files in httpd.conf: I quoted it above.  Did you mean something else?
In case having two methods of handling .php files was the cause of the problem, I removed .php from the <Directory> section in my user-specific configuration file and restarted the server, to no effect.
I remain concerned that the ServerAdmin email address in the error message does not correspond to the address I defined in httpd.conf.
I appreciate your suggestions.  Thank you.

You definitely need to restart the http server process (apache) after having made changes to those configuration files. Once on it also check if that path /private/var/log/apache2/error_log really is the one that is configured as error log file. That "private" in there looks funny to me. Such an error log file always has entries, not only in case of an error. So also check if the logging function is enabled at all.

About CGI: Indeed you can use php via the CGI interface, but you probably don't want that. Instead you want to either use PHP as a module inside the apache http server or you want to start a separate fastCGI container (a separate server instance) for PHP. For development purposes I would always recommend the module approach.

You probably need something like AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php to use php via the module inside the http server.

@arkascha: I've edited my question to provide additional information that I hope addresses your queries.

First make sure that the http server process really is restarted. I suspect that sudo launchctl remove org.apache2.httpd not really restarts the running process, but only removes that service from the list of services to be started. I am not familiar with MacOS (as a developer I prefer Linux for obvious reasons), so I cannot say. Just test it: run that directive and make a test request. Does your http server respond (always make a deep reload, better even always use a fresh anonymous browser window to not fall for pages cached in the browser). If in doubt then simply reboot the system.

Everyone uses Docker these days to get a consistent development environment across platforms, so I'm going to recommend you do the same!
I use a MacBook Pro, and the only tools installed are Docker, Git, Sequel Ace for connecting to my DBs, and PHPStorm, my IDE.
With Docker you have a tool called docker compose which lets you start up containers. Here is my LAMP stack docker compose file (from https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp):
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    db_data:
        driver: local

services:
    awesome.scot:
        build:
            context: ./build
            dockerfile: ./httpd/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes_from:
            - app

    php:
        build:
            context: ./build
            dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 9000
            - 9001
        volumes_from:
            - app
        environment:
            APPLICATION_ENV: '${APPLICATION_ENV}'
        user: php:staff

    node:
        build: ./build/node
        volumes_from:
            - app
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 3000:3000

    app:
        image: httpd:2.4.38
        volumes:
            - ./code:/var/www/html
        command: "echo true"

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.7.1
        volumes:
            - ./build/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '[123456]'
            MYSQL_USER: dbuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '[123456]'
        ports:
            - 3306:3306

    mail:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025

Without explaining absolutely everything here, when you start it up you get an Apache container, PHP, MySqL, Node, MariaDb, and MailHog, and you just drop your code in the code folder.
Typically you start everything by saying docker compose up (In my git project I have made some bin/ scripts that call this so I usually just need to type bin/start and bin/stop).
Anyway, more details on how it works can be found in the README.md, so I encourage you to give it a try using my setup as a starting point, and tweak the settings for your needs!

Thank you.  I'm a Docker novice, but it is definitely an option I want to explore.

Give it a shot!  Install Docker, clone my LAMP stack repo  linked above, cd into the folder, and run bin/start, and that's you up and running!
